# Error in showing points on a line graph using java

Tags: java

This creates a graph but only the first point and number will show, the rest will stay at that number. The goal of the graph is to represent the popularity of certain Baby Names from the years 1900-2000 in increments of a decade. e.g. 1900:, 1910:, 1920:...
Below is the code.

g is graphics

````
Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(nameFile);
        boolean found;
        while (fileScan.hasNextLine() && counter == 0) {
            String next = fileScan.nextLine();
            Scanner token = new Scanner(next);
            String checkName = token.next();
            found = checkName.equals(name);

            if (found) {
                int pop = token.nextInt();
                if (pop == 0) {
                    pop = 1000;
                }
                g.drawString("" + pop % 1000, 0, pop / 2 + 30);
                int lastPop = pop;
                //
                for (int i = 1; i <= (decades - 1); i++) {
                    pop = token.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(pop);
                    if (pop == 0) {
                        pop = 1000;
                    }
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.drawString("" + pop % 1000, i * width, pop / 2 + 30);
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g.drawLine((i - 1) * width, lastPop / 2 + 30, i * width, pop / 2 + 30);
                    lastPop = pop;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
    ```
````

Comment: Please post the whole code. What is `g`.

Comment: Yes, g is graphics! But where do you get g at this point? What is the function of your code? Is it `paintComponent` of a `Jpanel` or a function that is called from there?